# Generate well formed routes from MenuBuilder class in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu, symfony-routing

I've this route defined in a controller:

```
/**
 * @Secure(roles="IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY")
 * @Route(
 *        "/proccess/{slug}", 
 *        requirements={"slug": "^([a-zA-Z0-9]*-[a-zA-Z0-9]*)+$"}, 
 *        name="registerRPNI"
 * )
 */
public function indexAction(Request $request)
{
    ......
}
```

And I need to set the right route in KNPMenuBundle MenuBuilder class. I'm doing as follow:

```
->addChild('Process RPNI', array(
     'uri' => '/process/national-and-imported-products-registration',
))
```

And it works for `dev` environment since route shows the right page and execute the right code but if I move away from `dev` and goes live to `prod` then I got a `404 Not found`, what I'm doing wrong in this case? What should be the right way to generate the routes inside the `MenuBuilder` class? Any advice around this?

Comment: Why not just use `'route' => 'registerRPNI', 'routeParameters' => array('slug' => 'national-and-imported-products-registration')` as you would usually?

Comment: @Qoop I did not know that way until now, I figure out how to get it done by injecting "`@route`" to the service where KnpMenu is defined and then setting this `$this->router->generate('registerRPNI', array('slug' => 'registerRPNI'))` to the `uri` param. I think is the same approach in different flavors, right?

Comment: You don't even need to do that. The menu factory already has the route generator so you can add a route and routeParameters in a childs attributes and it will generate the uri for you. Check out https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/index.md#method-a-the-easy-way-yay